# Nested ManytoMany Serialization in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my app I have a nested many to many relation like the following:

Models.py

```
class ReturnKitsProducts(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class ReturnKits(models.Model):

    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(ReturnKitsProducts)


class Return(models.Model):

    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    transaction_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    flow = models.ForeignKey(Flow, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    kits = models.ManyToManyField(ReturnKits)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In this `ReturnKitsProducts` is connected to `ReturnKits` as M2M and `ReturnKits` is connected to `Return` as M2M. I have handles only single level of M2M serialization for updatation and creation like this:

Serializers.py

```
class ReturnKitsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ReturnKits
        fields = "__all__"

class ReturnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    kits = ReturnKitsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Return
        fields = "__all__"


    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('kits', None)
        prdcts = []
        for item in items_objects:
            i = ReturnKits.objects.create(**item)
            prdcts.append(i)
        instance = Return.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print("prdcts", prdcts)
        instance.items.set(prdcts)
        return instance
```

But I am not sure how to do serialization in the above mentioned scenario. Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ReturnKitsProducts
        fields = "__all__"

class ReturnKitsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True)  # same as 

    class Meta:
        model = ReturnKits
        fields = "__all__"

class ReturnSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    kits = ReturnKitsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Return
        fields = "__all__"


    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_objects = validated_data.pop('kits', None)
        instance = Return.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item in item_objects:
            return_products = item.pop('items')
            i = ReturnKits.objects.create(**item)
            for data in return_products:
               return_product = ReturnKitsProducts.objects.create(**data)
               i.items.add(return_product)
            instance.items.add(i)
        return instance
```

What I did was pulling out the data from the `validated_data` dictionary and create instances as necessary.

Comment: Iterating through and creating items in different transactions is too expensive. For me a solution would include to create them with a bulk update.